# Will fuild in the red circuit mix in the blue circuit

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

I have a conceptual question regarding hydraulic circuits. I have two circuits A(blue) and B(red), connected by a 3 way valve. The following are description about the circuit

[image]

1. A and B, containing coolant liquid at 1 atmosphere
2. Circuit A can be connect to Circuit B by via a three way valve
3. Pump P1 in circuit A, is 2.2x powerful than pump in P2 circuit B
4. At the top part, both the circuits connect into pump P1

My question is

1. If the 3 way valve is kept closed, meaning, coolant from circuit A does not
   flow in circuit B, and Pump P1 is running and P2 shut off, will any liquid
   from the circuit B (red circuit) will get sucked into circuit A at the
   entrance of Pump P1 ?
2. What would be the result if Pump P2 (in circuit B) is also running, and the 3
   way valve is closed (meaning the fluid from circuit A is not allowed to go into circuit B) ?

My hypothesis is that since the fluid is being pumped in circuit A, the pressure in circuit A will be higher than in Circuit B. This would naturally block the fluid from circuit B from mixing into circuit A, when the 3 way valve is closed

Is my hypothesis correct, if not, what could be the explanation behind such an effect ?

Answer (score 0):

From the purely hydraulic point of view (incompressible fluid, small pipe diameters), B would not form a circuit that includes P1 and hence fluid from B would not mix into circuit A.

However, talking about reality, what if the fluid in B contained genetically engineered anthrax virus, and A contained drinking water. Would you drink it? I wouldn't, because real pipes have a diameter and real fluids are compressible. At the T-junction close to P1, small amounts from B would mix into A due to vortices and fluid expansion responding to underpressure, which would eventually kill you and all your family, possibly also the whole city, country or world.

So, it depends on the level of required accuracy and safety whether you consider the two circuits mixing under a closed three-way valve.

If small mixing is uncritical, both circuits are only connected statically (over the small red line at mid-top) if the 3-way valve is closed. Any amount of liquid that flows along the small mid-top red pipe would have to increase the mass in the red circuit and decrease the mass in the blue circuit or vice-versa, which would be a violation of incompressibility. The situation changes, however, if you have reservoirs (compensation vessels, or pipes are elastic) in both circuits, or the fluid becomes compressible (gas). Then flow across the upper bridge would become possible, depending on the amount of elasticity present.

Comment: I have updated the circuit diagram and question description, as the ealier diagram had both the pumps marked as P1. Would you explanation change in this situation

Also can you please elaborate more why would the fluid from circuit "B" not enter "A" in both situation (1) and (2) that I have asked. From our system perspective it is okay to have small mixing

Comment: @MasoomKumar I didn't even notice that the other pump was also denoted by P1. Nothing changes about the explanation. It is also irrelevant if the other pump P2 is running or not, see my edited question.

Comment: So as per your explanation, it is the incompressible nature of the fluid that prevents fluid from the red circuit from barging into the blue circuit, when the three way valve is closed at the bottom (to prevent liquid from circuit B going into circuit A)

Also you have talked about "violation of incompressibility". Can you please provide bit more isight via mathematical equation regarding what you mean ? I am not good with fluid statics / dynamics

Comment: So do you mean to say that in a non compressible flow, the mass through the control volume should be constant. Then if we imagine a control volume in circuit A, then any addition of fluid from circuit B will lead to the violation, and hence a mixing wont take place, until as you stated that the liquid becomes compressible, or the pipes become elastic!